# glyphicons don't working on compass-sass 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying the glyphicons to show up on my local view, but nothing at all.\
I've change the path on _bootstrap-variables.scss to ../fonts/bootstrap/ also tried the @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; on my styles.css but nothing at all, someone please help me , also why the bullets aren't showing when using carousel?